# How to copy line in XAML editor?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, hotkeys

In Visual Studio.NET when coding I constantly use (no selection) CTRL-C, CTRL-V to make a quick copy of a line.

Unfortunately this works differently in the XAML editor (it pastes the new line in the middle of the current line).

Does anyone know the hotkey to copy a line in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map the .xaml extension to the standard XML editor this problem will be solved along with others such as the poor performance of the XAML editor.

Tools / Options / Text Editor / File Extension

Answer (score 0):

In the XAML editor in Visual Studio 2010 (and the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview), copying and pasting a line has the expected behavior:

- Invoking a copy when there is no selected text causes the entire current line to be copied.
- A subsequent paste when there is no selected text will cause the copied line to be inserted above the current line.